# PHP sort multidimensional array by date

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting

I'm having a problem. I have a multidimensional array, that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 
              Array ( 
                    [0] => Testguy2's post. 
                    [1] => testguy2 
                    [2] => 2013-04-03 
              ) 

        [1] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Testguy's post. 
                    [1] => testguy 
                    [2] => 2013-04-07 
              ) 
);
```

I want to sort the posts from the newest date to the oldest date, so it looks like this:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( 
                     [0] => Testguy's post. 
                     [1] => testguy 
                     [2] => 2013-04-07 
               ) 
        [0] => Array ( 
                     [0] => Testguy2's post. 
                     [1] => testguy2 
                     [2] => 2013-04-03
               ) 
);
```

How do I sort it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b){

    $a = strtotime($a[2]);
    $b = strtotime($b[2]);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Or for >= PHP 7

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a[2]) <=> strtotime($b[2]);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `usort` with a `Closure` :

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a[2]);
    $b = strtotime($b[2]);
    return (($a == $b) ? (0) : (($a > $b) ? (1) : (-1)));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just stepping away from my desk for the day so I can't offer specifics. But here's a good place to get started that includes examples: [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array();       
foreach($a AS $val){
    $dates[] = strtotime($val[2]);
}
array_multisort($dates, SORT_ASC, $a);
```

Comment: It would be considered to be nice to add some explanation around your code.